# Git merge in wrong direction

Tags: git, merge

I have finished a lengthy merge of a **devel** branch onto **master**, then I realised it should have been a *devel update* instead, meaning the direction should be **master -> devel**. Is it possible to change the destination 
of the commit, so that the arrow is pointing from master to devel?

note: The resulting changes in files would be exactly same for both `d->m` and `m->d`. It's just the final destination (and arrow in history) which is wrong.

now: [image] desired: [image]

```
blue: master
red: devel
```

***Changes are not commited or pushed yet.**

### Recapitulation

> - I resolved all conflicts in a **devel->master** merge.
> - I haven't
>     commited or pushed the changes.
> - Changes are made on top of master.
> - I
>     need to apply the resolved conflicts in a **master->devel** direction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reverting a merge on the branch is as simple as determining which commit was the previous one.

First, checkout on the branch you want to modify. **It's a git-golden-rule: you can only modify the branch you're on.**

```
git checkout master
```

Then, figure out the previous-master commit it, and force master back into its previous state

```
git reset --hard <previous-commit-id>
```

Finally, do your merge right

```
git checkout devel
git merge master
```

---

What you could also do, if you want to be lazy, is invert branch states.

You still need to find master's previous commit-id.

Then:

```
git checkout devel
git reset --hard master
git checkout master
git reset --hard <previous-commit-id>
```

Comment: I haven't commited nor pushed it yet, but I don't want to do the lengthy merge all again (it was a difficult one), since I would have made it exactly the same.

Comment: Can I possibly stash the finished merge, initiate `master -> devel` merge, discard conflicts, apply stash and commit?

Comment: Edited my answer @Qwerty

Comment: I am kinda lost in it. When do I commit and push the changes? Let's recapitulate: 1) I resolved all conflicts in a devel->master merge. 2) I haven't commited or pushed the changes. 3) Changes are made on master. 4) I need to apply the resolved conflicts in a master->devel direction.

Comment: @blue112 as per my knowledge If there are merge conflicts, you have to fix them again when merging into correct branch, if theres better way someone please tell.

Comment: Oh, you haven't commited your conflicts. Commit them on master, and the apply the procedure on the second part on my post.

Comment: Okay, thank you, the second part really worked!! ..and I didn't have to make the merge again.

Comment: @Qwerty: FYI if you want to avoid repeatedly fixing merge conflicts, you might be able to use `git rerere` to reuse recorded resolutions

Comment: Thank for the solution (first part)! Really help also after committing and pushing.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually a bit simpler than anwser of @blue112 .
First commit the master locally.

```
git checkout master
git commit
```

This will create a shared commit for master and devel.
Then switch to devel and merge it also with master. This will result in a fast-forward merge as there aren't any conflicts left.

```
git checkout devel
git merge master
```

It should be save to push devel now.

```
git push devel origin/devel
```

Now revert master back to its previous commit, so it remains as it was before the merge:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard <previous-commit-id>
```

Workspace should be clean and safe now.

Answer (score 0):

I would force the devel branch to take on current master's HEAD, and then reset master's HEAD back one commit.  Like so:

```
git checkout master    
git branch -f devel HEAD          # force "devel" to equal current "master"
git branch -u origin/devel devel  # set "devel"'s upstream tracking.
git reset --hard HEAD~1           # set "master" back one commit.
```

And then if you like what you see...

```
git checkout devel
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid losing any work, given your exact situation, I would force the devel branch to take on current master's HEAD, and then reset master's HEAD back one commit.  Like so:

```
git checkout master    
git branch -f devel HEAD          # force "devel" to equal current "master"
git branch -u origin/devel devel  # set "devel"'s upstream tracking.
git reset --hard HEAD~1           # set "master" back one commit.
```

And then if you like what you see...

```
git checkout devel
git push
```